# java 1.7+ is not supported in -source 1.5 errors

Tags: java, maven, configuration, version, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm getting all sort of java errors not supported in -source 1.5 when creating my Maven Install in eclipse.  There is nothing wrong with my code.

Errors follows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1
[23,62] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5 
[241,29] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
[156,64] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
```

My pom configuration follows:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Please upgrade your maven-compiler-plugin version....The configuration is given for the maven-war-plugin which does not handle such configuration. The plugin is maven-compile-plugin instead... Why do you have a separate maven-war-pugin configured? Furthermore if you like to set encoding please set the property: `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>` that  will make the  `<encoding>..</encoding>` in your configuration superfluous.

Comment: I am not interested to replace the "maven-war-plugin" with "maven-compile-plugin".  The reason why is that it will give me a Warning "An illegal reflective access operation has occurred" when i upgrade to jdk 1.9+.   Thanks K for the advice about the sourceEncoding. I will try it :)

Comment: Please follow khmarbaise's advice. You use the the maven war plugin incorrectly. The configuration need to be in the maven compile plugin.

Comment: The error message is telling you that there is a problem with maven-compiler-plugin.  That is the configuration you need to fix, not maven-war-plugin.

Comment: Consider using a better IDE which can help you fix things like this.

Comment: @VGR, the maven-compiler-plugin is nowhere found in my pom.xml file.  Therefore, i assume if not provided, an internal version can be used when running from Maven Build Install and/or if it is provided from the pom in the <properties> section.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following lines in your pom.xml file should resolve your problem.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

for java 11 use:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

If you may take in consideration the advises that were provided to you. You would have 2 options to choose from:

**Option 1)** If you keep the maven-war-plugin. Update version to the latest then add the properties with the compiler info and sourceEncoding but **remove the configuration lines**:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    
    ..
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </plugin>
    ..
</build>
```

**Option 2)** If you replace maven-war-plugin with the maven-compiler-plugin ** There are no need to add/replace the source, target and encoding to the properties**.  Make sure to update the version to the latest:

```
<build>
    ..
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ..
</build>
```